# Windows Explorer extension Delphi XE5 and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe5

My code nothing happens. What is missing to implement or there is any restriction on Windows 8.1 for x64 Shell Extension ?

Use
Delphi XE5

Windows 8.1 x64

```
unit uModuloIpm;

interface

uses
  Windows, ComObj, ActiveX, Modulo_TLB, StdVcl, ShlObj, Registry;

type
  TCoModulo = class(TAutoObject, ICoModulo, IExtractIcon)
  protected
    function GetIconLocation(uFlags: UINT; szIconFile: LPWSTR; cchMax: UINT;
      out piIndex: Integer; out pwFlags: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
    function Extract(pszFile: LPCWSTR; nIconIndex: UINT;
      out phiconLarge, phiconSmall: HICON; nIconSize: UINT): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TCoModuloObjectFactory = class(TAutoObjectFactory)
  protected
    procedure ApproveShellExtension(&Register: Boolean; const ClsID: string);
    function GetProgID: string; override;
  public
    procedure UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean); override;
  end;

implementation

uses ComServ, SysUtils;

procedure TCoModuloObjectFactory.ApproveShellExtension(Register: Boolean;
  const ClsID: string);
Const
  WinNTRegKey =
    'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved';
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg:= TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey:= HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if not Reg.OpenKey(WinNTRegKey, True) then
      Exit;
    if &Register then
      Reg.WriteString(ClsID, Description)
    else
      Reg.DeleteValue(ClsID);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

function TCoModuloObjectFactory.GetProgID: string;
begin
  Result:= GUIDToString(IID_ICoModulo);
end;

procedure TCoModuloObjectFactory.UpdateRegistry(Register: Boolean);
Const
  ColumKey = 'Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers\%s';
begin
  inherited UpdateRegistry(Register);
  ApproveShellExtension(Register, GUIDToString(CLASS_CoModulo));
  if Register then
    CreateRegKey(Format(ColumKey, [GUIDToString(CLASS_CoModulo)]), '', '', HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)
  else
    DeleteRegKey(Format(ColumKey, [GUIDToString(CLASS_CoModulo)]), HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT);
end;

function TCoModulo.Extract(pszFile: LPCWSTR; nIconIndex: UINT; out phiconLarge,
  phiconSmall: HICON; nIconSize: UINT): HResult;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'Extract','',0); // Only to trigger the event
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TCoModulo.GetIconLocation(uFlags: UINT; szIconFile: LPWSTR;
  cchMax: UINT; out piIndex: Integer; out pwFlags: UINT): HResult;
begin
  MessageBox(0,'GetIconLocation','',0); // Only to trigger the event
  Result := S_OK;
end;

initialization
  TCoModuloObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TCoModulo, Class_CoModulo,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

Everything works fine in that scenario, when implement IContextMenu based on this example http://www.andreanolanusse.com/en/shell-extension-for-windows-32-bit-and-64-bit-with-delphi-xe2/.

Comment: 64 bit shell extensions work fine in Delphi. You should do some debugging. Add trace logging.

Comment: What your shell extension should do? GetIconLocation and Extract are methods of icon handler, but in UpdateRegistry you try to register column handler.

Comment: already tried implementing IColumnProvider, but nothing happens also

Comment: Windows does not support IColumnProvider starting from Vista.